# Object Detection API Assertion failed: [maximum box coordinate value is larger than 1.01: ] for resnet models in

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I'm using Tensorflow's [Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection), but get the following error when training:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): assertion failed:
>   [maximum box coordinate value is larger than 1.01: ] [1.47]

I get the error when I use any of the following:

- faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco
- rfcn_resnet101_coco

But NOT when I use:

- ssd_inception_v2_coco
- ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco

My training images are a mixture of 300x300 and 450x450 pixels. I don't believe any of my bounding boxes are outside the image coordinates. Even if that's the case why would the last two models work but not the resnet models?

Comment: might be the image preprocessing pipeline performing image/label augmentation via some random transformations.  See if you can find the offending input.

Comment: Thanks, but I even tried it without any augmentation and still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at my raw bounding box data, turns out there were a few random instances where the bounding box coordinates either had very large numbers or negative numbers (not sure how that happened to begin with). I deleted these and now I have no issue training any of the models.

Answer (score 2):

The first two networks you mentioned seem to be using a value between 0 and 1 to define the position of the bounding boxes. For that reason, I was getting the same error.

I had to change the script to create the TF records, from something like this:

```
# Assuming `x` & `y` are floats with the coordinates of the top-left corner:
xmin = x
ymin = y

# Assuming `width` & `height` are floats with the size of the box
xmax = x + width
ymax = y + height
```

To something like this:

```
# Assuming `x` & `y` are floats with the coordinates of the top-left corner:
xmin = x / image_width
ymin = y / image_height

# Assuming `width` & `height` are floats with the size of the box
xmax = (x + width) / image_width
ymax = (y + height) / image_height
```

Comment: In my case it is already changed, do you ahve any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. For me, when I was converting xml files to csv, I was indexing the values (width, height, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) from the xml tree. For this, I was assuming a particular xml structure for all records. This was the problem for me.

> This is what I did for accessing value of xmin:

```
object.find('bndbox')[0].text
```

Instead, I accessed the values using key values. This solved it for me.

> The correct way:

```
object.find('bndbox').find('xmin').text
```