# Amount of memory needed for training with faster_rcnn and rfcn models

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I've been trying to make some trainings using some faster_rcnn and rfcn based models, using Google's Object Detection API, but after some training steps i get some errors regarding, what i assume to be memory issues. What is considered a good amount of free RAM before starting making a training  with the above models?

Here is some of log errors:

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): assertion failed: [maximum box coordinate value is larger than 1.010000: ] [1.0111111]
     [[Node: Loss/ToAbsoluteCoordinates/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert = Assert[T=[DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT], summarize=3, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Loss/ToAbsoluteCoordinates/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch/_1307, Loss/ToAbsoluteCoordinates/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_0, Loss/ToAbsoluteCoordinates/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_1/_1309)]]

Comment: Look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135528/object-detection-api-assertion-failed-maximum-box-coordinate-value-is-larger-t

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not for OOM error. It should be something wrong with your bounding boxes. Go for a check if your xmax or ymax values are biger than the width and height value. Not enough memory should be look like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1Zoe.jpg)